# Add Kendo UI MVC reference to Unit Test project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I am trying to add kendo mvc ui reference to unit test project but it doesn't affect.

How can I add reference kendo mvc ui dll to existing unit test project?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "can't add reference"? Do you get some error message when selecting the dll? Does it show on the list af available assemblies at all? Does it appear in the references but with a yellow icon?
Check the target framework version of the unit test project, in case it is not high enough for the Dll you want to add.